# Is it mandatory to use cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix() on cv2.undistort?

Tags: opencv, process, calibration

In my last stage of my thesis, i have to compute 3D bounding boxes through two ip cameras using yolo. I have already found my exterior orientation with **cv2.solvePnp()** using some ground truth values ( measured values of points on the wall of the room ) and done calibration with **rational model** enabled because my cameras are wide lens. All i am asking is, through the whole process, do i have to use **cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix()** on **cv2.undistort()** in order to correctly continue through my 3d bounding box or not? Because my results with non using it, with parameter **alpha = 0** and **alpha = 1** seems quite correct to me.